# In react native app (through Expo) using firestore permissions - request.auth is always null

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Here's my code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        console.log("We are authenticated now!");
        firebase.firestore().collection("users")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({ name: "new name" });
    } else {
        loginWithFacebook();
    }
});
```

And, here are my permission rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like no matter what, request.auth is always null. 
The error I get:

> Firestore (4.8.0) 2017-12-20T04:18:27.321Z [Connection]: WebChannel
>   received error: {"code":403,"message":"Missing or insufficient
>   permissions.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}

Comment: How did you test this? You can't print the value of security rules, so what did you use to verify it's always null? How did you verify you're connecting to the right endpoint? Nothing you have here looks like an issue, so there's something missing.

Comment: @Kato - simple: with `allow read, write: if true;` I get to read&write to db, while with `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` I get permission error, meaning request.auth is null.

Comment: Can it be related to this? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/283#issuecomment-3458155791

Comment: Are you sure request.auth is the correct location to check?

Comment: It doesn't mean that request.auth is null. It could simply be that you're trying to connect before auth is reconciled.

Comment: Thanks @Kato, I'm doing it only after onAuthChanged if user...

Comment: Something else must be at play here. If you make this a fully working example I could try locally against my own project, I'd be happy to look.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. I'm trying to write a document right after I authenticate. I verified that the id is null by setting the rule to be 'request.auth.userId != null' and it still fails. I have not yet figured out what is wrong :(

Comment: @SavvasDalkitsis thanks - please write your comment as answer - so I can give you the bounty... Current answers are not answering the question and bounty has to be given in a few hours... We'll continue finding a fix to what seems a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the thought Ronen but that would pollute the answer list. The others, while not fixing the problem, are at least answers of sorts :)

Answer (score 5):

I downgraded to Firebase SDK 4.6.2 when I had this problem with latest Firebase JS SDK on Expo.

Also, you have to do this in order for everything to work:

Copy https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mikelehen/444950a35019208f3aaf18d37ab4937c/raw/85ac4cb3108d92163cb8f04fbdddcc88d4081aab/index.js

over your `node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.js`

Without this, you'll get nothing from your collections.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct solution for this issue

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Any chance you've submitted a bug report for this?

Answer (score 3):

I diffed the requests coming from the same code running in the browser vs expo. One difference I noticed was missing Origin header. I patched the xhr and it works for my uses. I'm not sure if this is a bug or expected behavior. I've asked on slack/firestore and discord/react-native but didn't get much input.

```
const xhrInterceptor = require('react-native/Libraries/Network/XHRInterceptor')
xhrInterceptor.setSendCallback((data, xhr) => {
  if (xhr._method === 'POST') {
    // WHATWG specifies opaque origin as anything other than a uri tuple. It serializes to the string 'null'.
    // https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin', 'null')
  }
})
xhrInterceptor.enableInterception()
```

Comment: You're a legend, Jade! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug - as other high-reputation users experienced it too. I'll update more when we find a fix. If anyone got it working (on react-native through expo) please share.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late to the party, but I just came across this and thought I'd share my experience. I had the exact same issue, and after months of researching and debugging, it resolved itself when I upgraded to firebase v 5. Here's a link to my SO post and solution. Hope it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51115385/6158840

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that issue by downgrading Firebase version to 5.0.0 (I was using version 6.4). Hope it could help others..

1. In your package.json

```
dependencies: {
  "firebase": "^5.0.0"
}
```

2. update dependencies

```js
npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

First check the Stuff on the FIREBSAE Rule Exectuion Simulator,

and secondly your issue sounds like you'r requests are not in Sync,
check your rules (if possible) in the Web view , as i tried doing the same and it worked for me

```
    {
      "rules": {
                ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null"
               }
    }
```

Comment: Question is about firestore rules - they are different than firebase's real-time-db. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please log your UID and confirm it is not null. Then modify the permission rule as -

```
// Grants a user access to a document matching their Auth user Id
    service cloud.firestore {
       match /databases/{database}/documents {
         // Collection named "users", document named after the userId
       match /users/{userId} {
         allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks - let me clarify: if you look close at the question - you'll see that everything is done only after user is signed in (by listening to onAuthChanged). And my rules are even less restricting than yours - all I check is for non null - and I get false all the time.