# Call to firestore collection() not working on expo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, promise, google-cloud-firestore

Using:
React Native with expo

react-redux: 5.0.6

redux: 3.7.2

firebase: 4.9.0

(See fix below: Downgraded to firebase 4.6.2)

UPDATE: This was a longer question based on the suspicion that redux wasn't working nicely with firebase. But that doesn't seem to be the case. Only keeping the relevant parts

This is an action creator hooked up with redux. 
When using `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` here, everything works fine.

**action.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

export const dataFetch = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('a@b.com', 'passw')      
        .then(
            (result => dispatch({ type: 'DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result })),
            (() => alert("got here"))
        )
        .catch((err) => alert(err))
    }
};
```

But when using `firebase.firestore().collection(...).get()`, execution doesn't go inside the `then()` part - can't log anything inside it.

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

export const dataFetch = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('MyCollection').get()
        .then(
            (result => dispatch({ type: 'DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result })),
            (() => alert("got here"))
        )
        .catch((err) => alert(err))
    }
};
```

What could be the issue? 
Is there a specific way to pass the collection path? 
Could the firebase config be incorrect? I double-checked everything at it looks right. I'm using the config for a web app. Is there something specific to firestore that could be missing?

I have the following keys in my firebase config:

```
apiKey: '',           // Auth / General use
authDomain: '',       // Auth with popup/redirect
databaseURL: '',      // Realtime Database
storageBucket: '',    // Storage
messagingSenderId: '',// Cloud Messaging
projectId: '',        // Firestore
```

Comment: if you logged `querySnapshot` in `dataFetch` , what you get?

Comment: Actually, the execution doesn't seem to be going inside the `.then()` after `.get()` at all. Is it because of the way the collection path is specified? Can't log querySnapshot.

Comment: I'm simply using the name `'MyCollection'` in the argument. Tried `'/MyCollection'` as well, doesn't work.

Comment: Double-checked my firebase config and everything looks right. How do I confirm I am connecting to the right database? I know, this sounds really basic, but I feel I'm not connecting to the db correctly. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: please check if `dataFetch` get called , add log statement in first line of the function

Comment: yes, dataFetch is being called. I can log before the line `firebase.firestore().collection(...).get() ... ` but not when execution is supposed to go in the promise `then()` section.

Comment: you may need to change the way how create the store , change to this `const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));`

Comment: Tried that, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the `firestore()` call inside `action.js`. When I'm making a call like `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(..., ...)` everything goes fine. But when I do `firebase.firestore().collection('MyCollection').get()`, execution doesn't enter the `then()` part, nor do I get an error in `catch()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so searched around a lot and found that it is a problem related to firestore not working with expo! (Updated title of the question to reflect this).

There is no stable fix for this but others have faced this issue and there is a workaround here, check answer by Igor:
[In react native app (through Expo) using firestore permissions - request.auth is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859246/in-react-native-app-through-expo-using-firestore-permissions-request-auth-is)

The issue is in React Native and has been discussed here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/283#issuecomment-345815579

Hopefully it will make it to the official builds soon.

FYI, I downgraded to firebase 4.6.2 and replaced the index.js file mentioned in the link above and things work perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what's going on in your code, but that self-invoking function seems kinda out of place? Reformatted your code to make it more readable to myself.

As you can see you forgot to close with } on the "result"-block + that self invoking function makes no sense? Why try and catch the error there when you already have a catch block?

```
export const dataFetch = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection('MyCollection').get()
    .then((result => {
            dispatch({ type: 'DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result }),
            (() => { alert("got here"); })
    )
    .catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
    });
};
};
```

Either way, this should work :

```
export function dataFetch (){
  const request = firebase.firestore().collection(`MyCollection`).get()
  return (dispatch) => {
    return request.then((result) => {
         dispatch({ type: 'DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result})
    }).catch((error)=> {
           console.log({error})
    })
  }
}
```

Not sure how and if your signInWithEmailAndPassword really does work.

Comment: My code is just another way to write the same thing. The syntantic error was while writing here in SO. Anyways, I've made it concise and simpler. And tried your version too. Still doesn't work. signInWithEmailAndPassword  works.

Comment: If I log the result of `const request = firebase.firestore().collection('MyCollection').get()`, I get an object `{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}`. No idea where this is coming from.