# request.auth.uid seems to always be null in Cloud Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I must be missing something really basic here... but any time I make a call to my Cloud Firestore db and I try to institute any kind of rules for security, they always fail.

Doing something like

```js
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow create, read, update: if true;
    }
```

works, but it obviously defeats the point. However, if I do any kind of additional scrutiny, such as the go-to example in all the docs like

```js
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow create, read, update: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
```

it fails every time. Am I missing something obvious in how I'm wiring together my client side code?

Here's my client side code that logs the user in, and then makes a call to the db to grab a user. 
(Note that in my db the keys for the users are by email, not by uid)

```js
// this is a snippet from the code where I log the user in
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, FIREBASE_USER_PASSWORD)
            .then(user => {
            // the user comes back successfully logged in, 
            // I grab its uid and add it to a preparedUser object that I've been building, 
            // then pass this user to my getFirestoreUserObject function
                preparedUser.uid = user.uid;
                getFirestoreUserObject({dispatch, user: preparedUser, navigate});
            })
            
// then the getFirestoreUserObject function:
// note that all the code below works fine when there are no security rules in place

const getFirestoreUserObject = ({dispatch, user, navigate}) => {
    const {name, email, imageUrl} = user;
    // if I ask for currentUser here, I get back my logged in user
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    // email is defined correctly here as the user's email
    firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(`${email}`)
        .get() // the request fails here due to insufficient permissions
        .then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                const currentUser = doc.data();

                getUserFavorites({dispatch, currentUser, navigate});
            } else {
                createUserInFirestore({dispatch, user, navigate});
            }
        })
};
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? If I log a user in via `firebase.auth()`, and then immediately after call `firebase.firestore()`, shouldn't that have the context of the auth'd user? If not, how do I pass it to the firestore call?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem here is _"immediately after"_. Like everything with firebase logging in is asynchronous, so it take a (short) while before its done.

Comment: Thanks, @AndréKool . Shouldn't the fact that the db call is made after the successful auth `.then()` block mean that the work on the firebase side is complete? Also, in my snippet above, when I call `currentUser`, before I reach out to the db, I successfully get back the currentUser from `firebase.auth()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After weeks of searching, and firestore and auth both working independently but not together... it was the most simple thing.

I was on firebase 4.x, which was the latest available when I started my project. Then, when I came around to adding auth rules, the latest published documentation on firebase for how to do the db rules (which I hadn't even looked at when I started, but came back to months later when I was ready to implement them) were listed using firebase 5.y. Updated my package.json, npm install, and everything magically worked :(

Hope this can help someone else... make sure you're on at least version 5!

Update emulators using: `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Comment: I'm having this same issue for Android using `'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'`.

Comment: @AdamHurwitz Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 3):

**June 2021**

Still have the issue with firebase cli 9.12.1.

Had to downgrade firebase JS to 8.3.1 to make it work but with that version it tries to verify the user online and not with the emulator

See [this post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3258)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but what ended up working for me is updating the `firebase cli` by running `npm install -g firebase-tools` which in turn updated the `cloud firestore emulator`

**NB:** There might be a different way of updating your firebase cli depending on the method of installation that you used. The above solution will work if you used `npm` to install the firebase cli. For other ways of updating the firebase cli, see the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `` firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(`${currentUser.uid}`).get() `` instead of `` firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(`${email}`).get() ``.

This is because your security rules

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow create, read, update: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

check for the uid of the user when determining whether or not to provide access to the data to the user, not the user's email.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My users are organized by email so I can tell who they are from the firestore list view on the console, without having to dive into each individual document. The issue ended up being a versioning one :( I left an updated answer above. Thanks again