# How to set Firestore Rule searching for a reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to request a user's `customerId` based on the user's `uid`, so that I can use that `customerId` for future reads/write within the application based on the denormalized structure of other collections.

[image: schema]

```
match /customers/{customerId} {
     allow read: if debug(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid) in resource.data.users);
     // allow list: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
     allow write: if false;
}
```

```js
const userRef = firestore
                .collection("users")
                .doc("AKwPD9IUq8oyLYb454XaA7JUmpyO")
await firestore
  .collection("customers")
  .where("users", "array-contains", userRef).get()
```

> FirebaseError:
> Null value error. for 'list' @ L13, Null value error. for 'list' @ L14

When I change to `read: true` or `list: true` the query is allowed (so I know it's the right `match`, just wrong rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So angry - the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/51115385/1166285

Firebase emulators were on different versions than my project's firebase packages, so `npm install -g firebase-tools` fixed it.

Wasted like 6 hours  i hope someone working at Firebase sees this!!