# Cloud Firestore: request.auth keeps returning "null"

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm developing an app with Remix together with the Firebase web SDK. I'm trying to write my security rules for my Firestore database, but I'm slamming my head for awhile now because I keep getting the "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions" error, even though I'm signed in (I used Google Sign in method). I use the following rule.:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something obvious I am overlooking?

EDIT:

```
export async function addUser(data: FirebaseUserFields) {
    const app =
        getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();

    const db = getFirestore(app);

    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", data.id), data);
}
```

I have a function that runs the `signInWithPopup` function within a React Context Provider:

```
const googleLogin = () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            .then((result) => {
                const credential =
                    GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
                const token = credential?.accessToken;
                // The signed-in user info.
                return addUser({
                    id: result.user.uid,
                    // ... additional data 
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setError("Sorry, something went wrong");
            });
    };
```

The following output I have when a user is succesfully logged in or has already logged in and my `onAuthStateChanged` function is triggered:

```
{
    "uid": "fR58htyWxWhVwUKbKTYYhCMq98f1",
    "email": "...",
    "emailVerified": true,
    "displayName": "...",
    "isAnonymous": false,
    "photoURL": "https://...",
    "providerData": [
        {
            "providerId": "google.com",
            "uid": "104448861784791813612",
            "displayName": "...",
            "email": "..",
            "phoneNumber": null,
            "photoURL": "https://..."
        }
    ],
    "stsTokenManager": {
        "refreshToken": "AOk..",
        "accessToken": "ey...",
        "expirationTime": 1673043376314
    },
    "createdAt": "1665760174513",
    "lastLoginAt": "1665902371045",
    "apiKey": "..",
    "appName": "[DEFAULT]"
}
```

Hope that does it!

Comment: Would you like to edit the question to show the code that makes the query, along with some evidence that shows the user is signed in.  For example, you could get a log the user's uid just before you perform the query.  We can't see what you're doing, so we don't know if what you're doing is wrong.

Comment: I edited my post. Hopefully it is more helpful to see my problem!

Comment: Have you tried setting `allow read: if true;` and `allow write: if true;`? This basically allow full access to your firestore, so you shouldn't get permission error. If you still do, then the problem might be with the setup of your firebase.

Comment: Yes, with these settings it does work and won't indeed get me a permission error.

Comment: Does the permission issue appear in `addUser()` function or does it appear somewhere else?

Comment: It appears when I'm trying to write rules for all my firestore documents, not specifically to `addUser()`

Comment: Is your `firebaseConfig` correct and updated? If so, can you provide evidence, like a screenshot, that the user is already signed in as per Doug's previous comment so that we could determine the main cause of this issue?

Comment: I am currently having the same issue with nextjs.   It looks like the auth property exists in the ui but not when needed at the firestore rules.    I believe this maybe an issue with firestore rules.  Still looking for a solution and will share if i find one.

Comment: I found this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224980/request-auth-uid-seems-to-always-be-null-in-cloud-firestore-rules.

Answer (score 2):

I'm replying to this most recent repost of this issue with firebase emulator authentication because I've wasted *so much time* trying to figure it out myself and it's constantly marked "resolved" when it very definitely isn't.

I finally found [the *correct* answer](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3258#issuecomment-1518506826) at the bottom of one of many, many threads on this topic, but added extra info for people using `npm` vs. `curl | bash` (is this world's worst practice?) to install and comments and a link to help you upgrade Java.

Basically, `firebase-tools` caches the binaries for the emulators and **nothing** you do to upgrade tools will fix this. Even so, you do want the latest version of `firebase-tools` so:

1. uninstall `firebase-tools` either using `sudo npm uninstall -g firebase-tools -g` or `curl -sL firebase.tools | uninstall=true bash` depending on how you installed them. (Do both! Enjoy!)
2. reinstall them using `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` (contrary to many reports, this works and is supported and doesn't involve piping shit into bash)
3. `rm -rf ~/.cache/firebase` (for macos, I don't know what the equivalent is on linux or Windows or if they even have this issue)
4. You may need to [upgrade Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) because of course you will (running `firebase-tools` will tell you).

Now fire up the emulator suite and firestore requests should actually work.

Comment: This is what I needed, thx. So frustrating as I also wasted a lot of time with the issue.